# How to define the Yoneda embedding

Tags: category-theory

I'm missing in my lecture notes the definition of "Yoneda embedding". It starts by saying that for a category $\boldsymbol{A}$ the Yoneda embedding is a functor $$ \boldsymbol{A} \rightarrow [\boldsymbol{A}^{op},Set],$$mapping objects $A$ to the hom-functor composed with $A$, i.e. $ A \mapsto Hom(-,A):\boldsymbol{A}^{op}\rightarrow Set$.

**But to what are the morphism mapped ?** This part I'm missing unfortunately and from what I could find on the internet, the definitions there look different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f\colon A\to B$ is a morphism in $\boldsymbol{A}$, the Yoneda embedding should send it to the morphism $\operatorname{Hom}(-,f)\colon\operatorname{Hom}(-,A)\to\operatorname{Hom}(-,B)$. This is a morphism in the functor category, meaning it should be a natural transformation between the hom functors, so you can describe it by its component morphisms.

I haven't rechecked the details, but I think for an object $X$, the component morphism $\operatorname{Hom}(X,f)\colon\operatorname{Hom}(X,A)\to\operatorname{Hom}(X,B)$ should just be post-composition by $f$, i.e., $f\circ -$. This should make all the naturality squares commute, as required. For if given some $g\in\operatorname{Hom}_{\boldsymbol{A}^\mathrm{op}}(C,D)$, commutativity of the corresponding naturality square amounts to checking if $f\circ(h\circ g)=(f\circ h)\circ g$, for any morphism $h\colon C\to A$.

Comment: Yep, that's right.